# hierarchical group django query

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to get a hierarchical group in categories using only one or maximum two django querysets. I got Django this model:

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    level = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Category')
```

and this is the queryset i got:

```
 categories = Category.objects.all().order_by("parent").order_by("level").values()
```

I'm trying to do this:

```
[
    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Tecnología",
    "level": "l1",
    "parent_id": null,
    "child":[
            {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Computación Lorem",
            "level": "l2",
            "parent_id": 1,
            "child":[
                    {
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "Portatiles",
                    "level": "l3",
                    "parent_id": 3
                    }
                    ]
            }
            ]
    }
]
```

I know this json has a new label ("child"). I can't create that, so i need a way to look close as possible to the top one. But this is what i got:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "level": "l1",
    "name": "Tecnología",
    "parent_id": null,
},


{
    "id": 3,
    "level": "l2",
    "name": "Computación Lorem",
    "parent_id": 1,
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "level": "l3",
    "name": "Portatiles",
    "parent_id": 3,
}
]
```

Can you people give me a friendly hand, please? i'll apreciate it so much.

Comment: Are you sure the best way to do this is by referring the FK to the Pk of its own table?

Comment: i got an old code that makes the query in 3 for cycles, but i have to refactor that. I've been looking for another ways, for example, this one:                                                           `categories = Category.objects.filter(level='l1').prefetch_related(child=Subquery(Category.objects.filter(parent=OuterRef('pk')).prefetch_related(child=Subquery(Category.objects.filter(parent=OuterRef('pk')).values() )).values() )).values()`. But i got stuck with a problem: _subquery can only have one column_. So i can't add the entire subquery as a "child" label.